# Is a good idea to use a SSL UCC certificate for two different but related web sites?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, ucc

There are two e-commerce sites on the same Apache server, moreover they share the same Drupal installation with common users and products. They differ for domain name and for aspect but are reciprocally linked.
Furthermore, my current apache version doesn't support SNI.

So, is a good idea using a SSl UCC certificate rather than two separate?

Comment: And you have one ipv4 address for each site, yes?

Comment: Not, I've an unique IP for both sites

Comment: @alez UCC is suitable for your situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these two websites have their own domain names, and they are all in the commercial usage. Thus, you want to encrypt the data for your customers.

**Situation one, the minimum cost is my world!**

```
Go get DC SSL * 2 for your websites, some vendors provide cheap SSL for as low as $5/year.
```

**Situation two, brand reputation is my heart!**

```
Go get EV SSL * 2, a green bar gives you a sugar bar due to most people regards the green bar as the better encryption and product guarantee evidence (EV verify the address and the business document of your business)
The cost for two EV per year is at least $500
```

**Situation three, get a balance between cost and brand!**

```
Go get UCC SSL which allows you to create at least 10 different domains (differed by vendors) in one certificate, 
avg price is $120/yr for one UCC.
```

However, if you build two websites to compete with each other for the same good, then you shouldn't get the UCC due to smart customers can easily find out what domains are protected by this certificate.

REMEMBER,

**The brand of SSL certificate doesn't indicate the data encryption level !!!**
You need to set the ciphers yourself.

Comment: Situation one, the problem is that my current apache version doesn't support more than one DC SSL on same IP, and... really $5/year? I've found only first year discounts at this price!

Comment: Sit. two: too expensive :)
Sit. three: as I've written, not only the two sites aren't in competition but also they are related and in collaboration. So, do you agree that is a good idea to use an UCC SSL?

Comment: @alez if both sites are in a collaboration or a business model you consider it is okay, then UCC is a great solution to you (CloudFlare uses UCC for SSL in some cases as well)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a UCC certificate is a good fit here.

You have a single Drupal multi-site installation serving two sites, which are somewhat related to each other.

The UCC certificate will allow you to:

- Use a single Apache web server configuration for both sites.
- Use a single IP address for both sites without requiring SNI. (But you still can waste extra IP addresses on it if you want.)
- Add more sites to Drupal and to the certificate later.

If you used separate certificates, you would need separate Apache virtual host configurations and separate IPv4 addresses for each site, greatly complicating the setup and constraining future expansion.